# Making a DOM element reference change to a null reference when removed from the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid, removechild

If I use `document.getElementById` to store a DOM element in a variable, and then remove the element from the DOM with the `removeChild` method, the object stored in the variable is not updated to a null reference. For example:

```
<div id="a">

</div>

<script>

  var a = document.getElementById('a');

  alert(a); // Alerts "[object HTMLDivElement]".

  a.parentNode.removeChild(a);

  alert(a); // Still alerts "[object HTMLDivElement]".

</script>
```

Is there any way to make the DOM element reference stored in the `a` variable more "live" in that it could detect when the element is removed from the DOM and thus be updated to `null` or whatever?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No there is not, that's the way it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because you store in a variable, just call var a = document.getElementById('a') when you need check.

> var a = document.getElementById('a');
>
> alert(a); // Alerts "[object HTMLDivElement]".
>
> a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
>
> a = document.getElementById('a');
>
> alert(a); // "undefined".

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. For some reason, I was thinking that the DOM element object stored in the variable was supposed to be "live", and change accordingly. That's fine that it isn't though. It just means that I have to insert an extra check into my code to verify that a DOM element is indeed valid before I use it. Thank you.